# Переключатель функции windows посредством .bat скрипта

Tags: windows, cmd, аудио, bat

В windows есть функция для звука - тонкомпенсация.

[image: Функция тонкомпенсации]

Время от времени приходится включать его чтобы услышать низкие частоты например в видео на сайте, а после просмотра видео отключить т.к. остальные звуки слишком громкие в этом режиме.

Необходимо сделать что то вроде переключателя, например создать bat файл и просто открывать этот файл мышкой или через горячую клавишу. Иначе приходится постоянно заходить в Звуки > Динамики > Улучшения > поставить галочку в Тонкомпенсация > Зарыть > Зарыть. И это уже реально начинает напрягать.

Нашел в реестре ключ этой функции:

[image: Ключ и значение тонкомпенсации в реестре]

и пробовал сам изменить его через bat файл:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Render\{b92e3a59-f027-42f8-976e-2f4ee264af90}\FxProperties" /v "{E0A941A0-88A2-4df5-8D6B-DD20BB06E8FB},4" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

значение в реестре успешно меняется, но самого эффекта увеличения низких частот (так как это происходит через ручное переключение как я описал выше) нет.

Нужно как то в bat файле прописать еще команды чтобы когда значение в реестре поменялось, система это как то применяла на вывод звука. Перезапускать службу звука через bat файл не хотелось бы, нужно именно применение сделанных изменений в bat файле.
А так же дописать условие if else - если значение в реестре стоит 0 то поменять его на 1 и наоборот - это при открытии bat файла.

Comment: Если выключить и включить устройство после изменения значения в реестре, новое значение применится?

Comment: Да, например после изменения значения в реестре я пробовал перезапускать стандартный видеоплеер и звук в этом видео значительно увеличился, без перезапуска этого эффекта нету. А так же эта галочка в первом скрине меняется.

Comment: В таком случае можно использовать что-то вроде [devcon disable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon-disable) для выключения и включения устройства из батника, подставив "ID экземпляра устройства" для этого аудио устройства из диспетчера устройств.

Comment: на гитхабе есть готовый [проект](https://github.com/TomasBisciak/Windows-Loudness-Equalization-toggle) для переключения тонокомпенсации. Правда сам проект для java, однако в комплекте есть скомпиленный экзешник. Короче, изучайте.

Comment: Тоже интересует этот вопрос, не нашли решение, поделитесь пожалуйста если нашли...

Comment: надобность в таком бат скрипте отпала, так как уже купил новое железо в котором есть софт с простым переключателем такой функции